# bzm - Concurrency Thread Group : need threads and same in same count

Tags: jmeter-plugins

I am using bzm - Concurrency Thread Group
Below image is my configuration
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQ3iM.png)

I am using Constant Throughput Timer with 50 but i am getting samples more than than 50 any suggestion pls
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5gpO.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. You have 50 users for 6 minutes running Samplers as fast as it can (the actual number will depend on the server response time)
2. You have Constant Throughput Timer set to execute 50 samplers per minute **per user** which means that 1 user will produce around 300 sample results per each sampler so 50 users will give you something like 15000

See [How do I Correlate the Number of (Concurrent) Users with Hits Per Second](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420695-How-do-I-Correlate-the-Number-of-Concurrent-Users-with-Hits-Per-Second) article for more details.

If you want 300 samplers for all users you need to set the timer to calculate throughput basing on all active threads (shared)

[image]

Or alternatively you can consider using [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) or [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer) instead

If you want to execute 50 samplers per user - you can also set Thread Iterations Limit to 50

[image]

If you want 50 samplers in total - set threads iteration limit to 1